# How can I create a ColorFunction using Blend?

Tags: graphics, color

As shown below, I am trying to find a cool way to show some variance weighted deviation from the mean. There are 10 attributes that I compute the distance for.

How can I add a color function such that it is progressively a darker shade of red when its value is negative (towards the left) and green when the value is positive (towards the right of the graphics)?

```
distance = {0.245, -0.235, 0.053, -0.048, -0.128, 
           -0.007, -0.075, -0.067,-0.005, 0.082}

Show[
  Function[
    attributes,
    Graphics[
      Rectangle[
        {If[distance[[attributes]] < 0, distance[[attributes]]*10, 0],
          attributes - 1},
        {If[distance[[attributes]] < 0, 0, distance[[attributes]]*10],
          attributes}
      ],
      PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 10}},
      Epilog -> {White, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 11}}]}
  ]] /@ Range[10], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Something like `Blend[{Darker[Red], Lighter[Green]}, #] &`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
distance = {0.245, -0.235, 0.053, -0.048, -0.128, -0.007, -0.075, -0.067, -0.005, 0.082}

Show[Function[attributes, 
   Graphics[{Blend[{{-Max[Abs[distance]], Red}, {0, LightRed}, {0, 
        LightGreen}, {+Max[Abs[distance]], Green}}, 
      distance[[attributes]]], 
     Rectangle[{If[distance[[attributes]] < 0, 
        distance[[attributes]]*10, 0], 
       attributes - 1}, {If[distance[[attributes]] < 0, 0, 
        distance[[attributes]]*10], attributes}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 10}}}, 
    Epilog -> {White, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 11}}]}]] /@ Range[10], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, looks like J.M. beat me to it.

Comment: I formatted your code. It is straightforward to do so, yourself: just indent the code by 4-spaces, or select the code and type ctrl+k.

Comment: He left a comment, not an answer. Yours wins by default.

Comment: Indeed, @rcollyer's right. ;)

Answer (score 10):

We can achieve such visual style with [**built-in tools**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0cq0nbvj-fhi6g2), applying some color gradient along the rectangles. Using your data:

```
distance = {0.245, -0.235, 0.053, -0.048, -0.128, 
           -0.007, -0.075, -0.067,-0.005, 0.082}
```

`BarChart` will do the job:

```
BarChart[distance, ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction[
"GradientScaleRectangle", "ColorScheme"-> "DarkRainbow"], BarOrigin ->Left,   
AspectRatio ->1, Frame ->True, GridLines -> {Range[-.22, .24, .02], Automatic}]
```

[image]

The horizontal scale is a bit different than yours, but you can easily adjust it. I personally enjoy very much that just a few lines will do things like:

```
BarChart[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 50}], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Axes -> None, 
BarSpacing ->{0, 0}, PerformanceGoal ->"Speed", ChartStyle -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

[image]

That was a [**Documentation example**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0cq0nbvj-g9ci5b).

Comment: How did you know about `ChartElementDataFunction`. I couldn't find it in documentation.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I now added a link to words **"built-in tools"** in the first line of the post to refer to the corresponding Documentation example.

Comment: Interesting that it turned up there but is not documented at `ref/ChartElementFunction` and doesn't seem to have its own documentation page explaining usage

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch If you search Documentation for `ChartElementDataFunction` - there will be many links. Because functions such as `SectorChart3D` have a special section in Documentation under Options dedicated to the usage of `ChartElementDataFunction`. But you're right - currently no separate article.

Comment: Just to qualify the comment at the start of this thread. I typed `?ChartElementDataFunction` and this failed to return a description.

Answer (score 9):

[Looking at David's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/976/7), it seems to me that you might want to

1. explicitly target the maximum and minimum values in your dataset to be pure green and red, respectively; and
2. have a neutral color, like gray, as the color at 0, so as to avoid the brownish colors in the middle.

To that end, I used this for the color:

```
If[distance[[attributes]] < 0, 
 Blend[{{Min[distance], Red}, {0, Gray}}, distance[[attributes]]], 
 Blend[{{Max[distance], Green}, {0, Gray}}, distance[[attributes]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

If you want red on the negative side and green on the positive side without having a transition from red to green, you could do something like

```
colorf = Blend[{Darker[Red, .7 #/Min[distance]],
  Darker[Green, .7 #/Max[distance]]}, UnitStep[#]] & ;

BarChart[distance,
 ColorFunction -> colorf,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 BarOrigin -> Left, Frame -> True, BarSpacing -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]