# Feed a Manipulate[] Output into a Graphics[]

Tags: graphics, manipulate

Please consider :

```
allTeamsOf5 = Subsets[Range[12], {5}];

rosterRandomAttributes = Table[Table[Round[RandomReal[], .1], {10}], {12}];

rosterRAMean = Mean@rosterRandomAttributes;

rosterRASD = StandardDeviation@rosterRandomAttributes;

allTeamStats = rosterRandomAttributes[[allTeamsOf5[[#]]]] & /@ 
               Range[Length@allTeamsOf5];

allTeamAverageStats = Mean /@ (allTeamStats[[#]]\[Transpose]) & /@ Range[792];

allTeamsDistToMean =
Total[(allTeamAverageStats[[#]] - rosterRAMean)/rosterRASD] & /@ Range[792];

distToMean = (rosterRandomAttributes[[#]] - rosterRAMean) & /@ Range[12];
```

The below essentially compute the best team we can get out of this roster emphasizing on different attribute through weight. It output a list of 10 value representing the distance to the mean for each.

```
Manipulate[(Flatten@
    allTeamAverageStats[[
     Flatten@Position[
       Total[{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10}/
       Total@{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10} (
       allTeamAverageStats[[#]] - rosterRAMean)/rosterRASD] & /@ 
    Range[792], 
   Max[Total[{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10}/
        Total@{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10} (
        allTeamAverageStats[[#]] - rosterRAMean)/rosterRASD] & /@ 
     Range[792]]]]]) - rosterRAMean,
 {v1, Range[.1, 1, .1]},
 {v2, Range[.1, 1, .1]},
 {v3, Range[.1, 1, .1]},
 {v4, Range[.1, 1, .1]},
 {v5, Range[.1, 1, .1]},
 {v6, Range[.1, 1, .1]},
 {v7, Range[.1, 1, .1]},
 {v8, Range[.1, 1, .1]},
 {v9, Range[.1, 1, .1]},
 {v10, Range[.1, 1, .1]}, ControlType -> Manipulator]
```

[image]

Now I would like the result of that manipulate to feed the below plot :
(using solution posted on [How can I create a ColorFunction using Blend?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/974/how-can-i-create-a-colorfunction-using-blend) )

```
Show[
 Function[attributes,
   Graphics[{
   Blend[{
   {-Max[Abs[distToMean[[1]]]], Red},
   {0, LightRed}, {0, LightGreen},
   {+Max[Abs[distToMean[[1]]]], Green}}, 
  distToMean[[1]][[attributes]]], 
 Rectangle[{If[distToMean[[1]][[attributes]] < 0, 
    distToMean[[1]][[attributes]]*10, 0], 
   attributes - 1}, {If[distToMean[[1]][[attributes]] < 0, 0, 
    distToMean[[1]][[attributes]]*10], attributes}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {0, 10}}}, AspectRatio -> 16/9, 
Epilog -> {Black, Thickness[.05], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 11}}]}]] /@ 
Range[10], Frame -> False, FrameTicks -> False]
```

[image]

**I would like the output of the manipulate to feed the Graphics instead of distToMean[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUDxy.png)]**
Trying to nest a With[] to avoid repeating the long code, failed for reason I came to understand. I still don`t know how I could solve my problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `Set` `dist[[1]]` to your output inside `Manipulate`. Putting additionally a `Dynamic` to your plots let's you see the change live.

(Edit) You can put your graphics of course inside the same `Manipulate` and change the graphics too. So *after* evaluating all your definitions from the first code-block, you could do something like

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   distToMean[[1]] = (Flatten@
       allTeamAverageStats[[Flatten@
          Position[
           Total[{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10}/
                Total@{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, 
                  v10} (allTeamAverageStats[[#]] - rosterRAMean)/
                rosterRASD] & /@ Range[792], 
           Max[Total[{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10}/
                 Total@{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, 
                   v10} (allTeamAverageStats[[#]] - rosterRAMean)/
                 rosterRASD] & /@ Range[792]]]]]) - rosterRAMean,
   Show[Function[attributes, 
      Graphics[{Blend[{{-Max[Abs[distToMean[[1]]]], Red}, {0, 
           LightRed}, {0, LightGreen}, {+Max[Abs[distToMean[[1]]]], 
           Green}}, distToMean[[1]][[attributes]]], 
        Rectangle[{If[distToMean[[1]][[attributes]] < 0, 
           distToMean[[1]][[attributes]]*10, 0], 
          attributes - 1}, {If[distToMean[[1]][[attributes]] < 0, 0, 
           distToMean[[1]][[attributes]]*10], attributes}], 
        PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {0, 10}}}, AspectRatio -> 16/9, 
       Epilog -> {Black, Thickness[thickness], 
         Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 11}}]}]] /@ Range[10], Frame -> False, 
    FrameTicks -> False]
   }, Center
  ],

 {v1, Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {v2, Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {v3, 
  Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {v4, Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {v5, 
  Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {v6, Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {v7, 
  Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {v8, Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {v9, 
  Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {v10, Range[.1, 1, .1]}, {thickness, 0.01, 0.1}, 
 ControlType -> Manipulator]
```

**Note:** This is far from being good programming style but for a test it should be fine.

Comment: No votes?  Looks good to me! +1

Comment: @Halirutan, I don`t know wether my previous comment got deleted. But, again, Thank You. Now what I wanted to do is to manipulate the graphics itself basically Sot have it within the manipulate object.

Comment: @500, see the edit in my post. You can of course put it in the same `Manipulate` and change the graphics there.

Comment: @Halirutan, THank You very much !